# Calibrating external monitors (HDMI, Mini DisplayPort)

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi, external-display, mini-displayport

I have a Dell XPS L502x laptop and two LG IPS235 monitors.
One of them connected through HDMI-HDMI, another through Mini DisplayPort - HDMI.

Although these are the same monitors, if I set them to default settings, the calibration is absolutely different. The default settings of the monitor, that is connected to GeForce GT 540M through HDMI - HDMI are very bad - the white is like yellow and the black is like gray. I tried to change that using the keys on the monitor and NVIDIA Control Panel, but I couldn't achieve the same result, as the other monitor.

Here is the screen shot of my NVIDIA Control Panel: Monitor 2 is connected through Mini DisplayPort - HDMI, Monitor 3 is connected through HDMI - HDMI.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the same problem if the HDMI to HDMI is in either monitor?

Comment: I wonder if that has something to do with your hdmi cable. Try switch your cable around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calibrate two monitors to the same video settings](http://superuser.com/questions/36492/calibrate-two-monitors-to-the-same-video-settings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options, none of which are built into Windows, but will get the job done:

1)I'd recommend this for something where you want the color close on both screens. One of [these tools](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-online-tools-calibrate-monitor/), and then tweak your color settings on both monitors until they are how you want them.

2)Professional shops like paint shops and printers use extra hardware to get the color just right on EVERYONE's machine, [something like this](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Color-Management-Hardware/ci/12000/N/4220238354). You basically hook it up and let it do it's thing.

So you have options, just depends on how serious you want to get.

Comment: Please be sure to put your answer on SE, instead of simply linking to another page. Links go dead and search engines have nothing to index.