# How can I improve yellow tint of on monitor?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display, amd-radeon, color-profiles

I have **Acer K222HQL** monitor, **AMD Radeon HD 8670M** graphic card. Connection through HDMI.

I tried different laptops, different OS (Linux distros, Windows), different ICC profiles (including IEC61966-2.1).

Tried connect to monitor with VGA, tried connect to TV using HDMI - the same problem.

Comment: @George J I was wrong, tint is everywhere

Comment: The one below looks closer to what my colour caliberated monitor shows. A *uncaliberated* monitor has a blue tint, and you're probably more used to it

Comment: @Journeyman Geek please read again last paragraph of my question, display has not blue tint - it's only on a photo.

Comment: But your previous commend suggests one monitor is *yellower* than the other. I'm seeing the exact same difference between my good factory colour calibrated monitor, my less good, hand calibrated monitor and my laptop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calibrating external monitors (HDMI, Mini DisplayPort)](http://superuser.com/questions/541150/calibrating-external-monitors-hdmi-mini-displayport)

Comment: How drastic is this yellow tint exactly? If it's just slightly yellow, then you can probably fix it. If it looks like the monitor is full of beer, then it's probably beyond "adjustment".

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 it is very noticeable on YouTube videos, while web-page's background is almost right white, if not the videos would not have noticed.

Answer (score 3):

The monitors are calibrated differently - though they might not be "wrong" as opposed to different. It feels like different colour temperatures to me.

The 'classic' colour temperature most higher end gear is calibrated against is 50K - this seems yellower compared to what most people are used to. Many consumer devices are calibrated for a bluer 65K colour temperature (or are uncaliberated and are closer to that).

A *quick* fix would be to toy with the 'colour temperature' or 'preset modes' till you find one that is 'right' for you. Since they are presets you can switch between them. I've never seen these on a laptop, but its something that works well on desktop monitors. You probably want a cool colour temperature or setting.

I have mismatched monitors, and wanted to go the cheap route (though I feel the defaults were *too* yellow on the non calibrated monitor) so I ended up running the calibration option on windows. This generates a colour calibration profile you can switch to as needed, based on adjustments you make - this would be a slightly more involved option, but it worked well for me.

If you want to get them as close to perfect as possible and don't want to do it by eye, I'd suggest using a calorimeter or a colour caliberation probe to  generate a *profile* and caliberate the monitor, though of course, this is a little overkill unless you do colour sensitive work.

If you want to know more - [I referenced this scientific american post a little](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/symbiartic/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor/) and the [first part is worth a read as well](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/symbiartic/professional-color-calibration-for-computer-screens/)

Comment: I tried to reduce red and green maximally - there are still no clear white color.