# Exactly same monitors bought 4 months apart, not the same output?

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, external-display

In my work place I use 2 monitors, they are both bought from amazon and both are same brand and model: Dell P2217H.

The one on the left is bought around 4 month after the one on the right.
[image]
[image]

They are both connected to the same docking station my laptop is connected to both using original display port cables that came with the monitors.

I checked 20 times that their settings are identical (I did factory reset to both of them anyway), I tried boosting their brighntess to 100% and did the comparison but the result is always the same, in other words, never the same.

The newer one (the one on the lefthandside) has much whiter whites. The 4 month older brother shows whites yellowish and brushed. It is like it was washed 1000 times together with socks and jeans.

It does not matter the "angle" you look at I look directly at both of them and the situation is just the same.

Is it normal for a monitor to lose its color and brightness in 4 months or is the first item defective? Or is it normal not to get the same quality from same models all the time? What may cause this very obvious difference in the colors and their quality?

Comment: "is it normal not to get the same quality from same models all the time"  It's normal. Check out https://superuser.com/questions/36492/calibrate-two-monitors-to-the-same-video-settings, and/or https://superuser.com/questions/22832/monitor-calibration-tools-and-software

Comment: You probably don't want 100% bright. That will make certain colors and intensities look washed out. Use a [calibration image](https://www.stegmann.dk/mikkel/photo/calibration/) to make sure you can get a clear distinction between every color bar. Only then adjust the full system up or down.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you swapped the connectors on the backs of the monitors? Does the degradation swap? This will check for differences in the video output settings and cables.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. No 2 LCD panels are exactly the same.
Even monitors that come from the production line in the same batch will not be the same.
Even very high quality and expensive monitors show more or less noticeable differences.
(It is far less visible on high-end stuff though as they tend to use better quality panels and they get pre-calibrated in the factory.)

That's why monitors need to be calibrated and really high-end monitors come with sophisticated calibration software and tools.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal. The specs have a small variance, and this is probably within spec limits.

If you buy two 2x4 pieces of wood, and measure them with a micrometer, there will be a difference too.

If it bothers you when using them (which is understandable - I actually have the same setup and had the same issue), you can calibrate both of them with whatever method, and the will be perfectly identical looking (although the settings values will be slightly different).