# Color management: How to calibrate my monitor?

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, color-profiles, calibration

Note:

- I pretty much don't have **any** knowledge of this topic whatsoever.
- I don't have any *calibration* tools, nor do I have any *calibrated* tools.

Is there a (free) way for me to figure out if my laptop's monitor is color-calibrated? And if so, how would I go about calibrating it in case it isn't?

The idea would be to match it as much as possible to the real world... but if that's more of a dream than reality, then please let me know. :)

(This is mainly for learning -- I'm not doing anything mission-critical, so I wouldn't care if the results aren't 100% precise.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitor Calibration Tools and Software](http://superuser.com/questions/22832/monitor-calibration-tools-and-software)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some [step-by-step instructions](http://beesbuzz.biz/art/tutorials/gamma.php) with pictures to test your monitor.
However our eyes (not actually the eyes, but the brain) is very adaptive "device". Calibration with your eyes is like lottery. You may do it better or worse. I recommend you to buy used [color calibration device](http://www.ebay.com/itm/130589155362) (and sell it after calibration). I did the same procedure few months ago. Only with device you can be sure that colors is matched correctly.

Comment: Up for your answer: buying a used colorimeter and selling it again works just as well as free.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a dream to match it as close as it is to the real world - that's what calibration is all about. Definitely no 100% match, but you can come close.

Use your eye, take a photo (best having whites, grays, and blacks in the scene) using a digital camera with Standard settings (or even maybe Neutral). Load the picture onto your computer and open it up.

Now, start adjusting using either built-in calibration software inside your OS, or using the monitor controls. Use your eye. Go for whites, grays and blacks. Adjust till you find them matching what your eye saw when you took the photo.

Quick guide can be found [here](http://tomyeah.com/monitor-color-calibration-for-free-using-your-dslr/).