# Windows 8 pale colors

Tags: windows-8

Just switched to Windows 8 and I noticed that the colors on some webpages are not the same as on my old laptop. On Windows 8 they look pale and I wonder if there is a problem with the depth of the colors or bad configuration on my OS. 
Is there somewhere where I can check my graphic card configuration or tweak the color confs?

Comment: You say that they are different from your **old laptop**, so I'm assuming this is a completely different computer. Different monitors typically display colors slightly differently, so it is likely a "problem" with your monitor's color calibration, not Windows 8. There's a guide on doing so [here](http://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor), though many other options are available.

Comment: The new laptop is supposed to have a better hardware (Lenovo U410 vs old Lenovo Y560).

Comment: @Armand - The color reproduction of LCDs is a fickle thing, and not at all related to the quality of the rest of the system sometimes (especially with Lenovo which has a bad habit of using lousy LCDs even in $3000 laptops...)

Comment: "Better" in terms of colors is highly subjective, and newer laptops don't necessarily have monitors with "better" color calibration. One person might prefer a lot of saturation, while someone else might like less saturation. This is why most monitors and TVs allow you to change such settings.

Comment: Maybe the "better" hardware is finally showing you the proper shades, but you _think_ they look pale in comparison to your old notebook because perhaps it wasn't showing them properly. :)

Comment: Thx Shinrai for the comment.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Color management: How to calibrate my monitor?](http://superuser.com/questions/409893/color-management-how-to-calibrate-my-monitor)

Comment: @techie007 just checked your link. I believe it is related to Windows7

Comment: @Armand Yeah but it's the same in Windows 8 (more or less). Admittedly the answers there are kind of link-only and low quality, but they lead to good info, and perhaps can be merged/generalized to include the info here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click on the desktop background
2. Go to `Screen Resolution`
3. Go to `Advanced Settings`
4. Under the `Adaptor` tab go to `List All Modes`

Choose your favourite mode with `True Color`

Answer (score 7):

I found colours on my laptop looked washed out, but Windows Screen Calibration fixed it up nicely.

To complete this routine:

- on the desktop, open Control Panel from the [Charms Bar](https://superuser.com/questions/493928/what-is-the-charms-bar)
- select `Colour Management`:

  [image]
- switch to the Advanced tab
- click `Calibrate display`:

  [image]

Comment: playing a little bit with Gamma improved a lot the color presentation.

Comment: This works for me but it resets every time I log out or switch user and does not re-apply when logging back in.